# Unable to generate Google OAuth 2 token

Tags: laravel-5, google-oauth, guzzle

I am trying to generate Google OAuth 2 token using GuzzleHttp on a laravel application but I am getting this error message -

```
Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }
```

Here is my code

```
 $client = new Client();
        $call = $client->post(env('AUTH_URL'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'redirect_uri' => env('CALLBACK_URL'),
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'scope' => env('SCOPE'),
                'code' => env('AUTH_CODE')
            ]
        ]);
        $response = json_decode($call->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        dd($response);
```

Please what might be the problem here?

Comment: 1) Remove the line `'scope' => env('SCOPE'),` 2) Did you request `access_type=offline` in your first call? 3) I would need to see the actual URL and headers that you generated to know what else is wrong - MASK THE CLIENT_ID when updating your question. 4) Good info on this error: https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I needed to re-generate the code plus, I added access_type=offline. Everything is good now.